# How to setup nginx + thin + multiple domains + multiple virtual hosts?

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, thin

I have a VPS. I create websites with Rails. I have several domains.

Now I want to install nginx + thin, and configure them to support `multiple hosts`, let each host have a seperated domain.

I have searched a lot, and now nginx and thin are installed and running, but I don't know how to combined them togetther.

Is there any articles or documents can help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I got it.

http://articles.slicehost.com/2009/4/17/centos-thin-web-server-for-ruby

http://articles.slicehost.com/2009/4/17/centos-nginx-rails-and-thin

http://cloudservers.rackspacecloud.com/index.php/CentOS_-_Adding_an_Nginx_init_script

http://cloudservers.rackspacecloud.com/index.php/CentOS_-_Nginx_from_source_layout

Comment: Please be sure to mark this as the "accepted" answer so the question may be resolved.